# Filter two letter domains

Tags: regex

I want to filter for specific two letter country domain endings in email. I've tried the following regex but it filters for more than two letter endings which I don't want. For instance, I want to filter `.co` but not `.com`.

```
(\w{2}|^)(\.(cn|co|cv))(\w{2}|$)
.*\.(cn|co|cv))$
```

What do I need to add or change in my regex so it only filters the two letter domain endings exactly as indicated?

Comment: Does [`\.(cn|co|cv)$`](http://regex101.com/r/yH5dH3/1) not work?

Comment: No. When I select "Body" and "matches regex" in CPanel and run a Filter Test with text ending in ".co", nothing is filtered.

Comment: The two RegEx I initially posted work in CPanel, but not just on the specific 2 letter endings; they work on anything that includes the "."  and the two letters - .co, .com, .company, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a word boundary instead of `$` anchor:

```
/\.(?:cn|co|cv)\b/
```

---

As OP comments as below, this addresses the issue:

```
"\w(\.(?:cn|co|cv))(?![A-Za-z0-9.=])"
```

or

```
"\.(?:cn|co|cv)(?![A-Za-z0-9.=])"
```

Comment: I use this RegEx to filter both body and header, so it's important not to filter negative lookahead for ">", "]", or white space, as these can sometimes follow two letter domain endings.
What exactly does "[^\W_]" cover? Alphanumeric (upper and lower case) or other characters too?

Comment: `[^\W_]` is the negated character class and negative `_`. As `\w` includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, `[^\W_]` means `[A-Za-z0-9]`, but way shorter and more readable!

Comment: How can I change RegEx so that the negative lookahead includes alphanumeric plus any other characters except >, ], and whitespace? CPanel doesnt work with [^\W_.] probably because the negated character class negates the ".", but does work with [A-Za-z0-9.] In addition to being followed by ".", I've now discovered a situation where two letter domain is followed by "=", so I've added that to RegEx [A-Za-z0-9.=] and it works fine. Hopefully, URL ending in two letter domain wouldn't be followed in body or header by anything but >, ], or whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me!

```
"\w(\.(?:cn|co|cv))(?![A-Za-z0-9.=])"
```

I also blocked other TLDs (.uk.org) by adding the following:

|uk.org| to the list.
It works like a charm.

Thanks

Comment: make that ......  |uk(backslash).org|